# Real * Bigint not return right value

Tags: sql, t-sql, math

I have two column in Sql server

1. Amount as real type
2. Price as bigint type

Amount is 3059.9 and Price is 29000

Price * amount should be 88737100 but it does not return correct value.

Should I cast any columns to other data type ?

 The result is 8.87371E+07, how can I display it without scientific notation?

Comment: What amount does result from the multiplication?

Comment: 8.87371E+07 _is_ 88737100, displayed in scientific notation.

Comment: how can I display it without scientific notation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL(38, 2)) * Price`.  Read up on [DECIMAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and adjust accordingly depending on the number of digits & decimal places.

Comment: @shaahin - you should consider changing the type of the Amount column to Decimal, rather than just casting it in this calculation.